# GSuite mobile devices API not returning all devices that are visible in the admin

Tags: google-workspace

I'm running the following code in the Google Script Console:

```
  var pageToken;
  var totalDevices = 0;
  do {
    var page = AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list(customerId, {
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < page.mobiledevices.length; i++) {
      totalDevices++;
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken)
  console.info("Found " + totalDevices + " mobile devices");
```

I'm expecting this to return all of the mobile devices in my organization, however I'm only seeing a subset. This prints that it found 19 total devices, but viewing my devices in https://admin.google.com/ac/devices/list shows that my organization has 34 devices.

Does this not list all devices by default? Is some parameter required to include all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobiledevices API does not return company owned devices, because it predates the introduction of that feature. There is no API for obtaining company owned devices.